# Static compression for static files in Websphere Application Server 9

Tags: websphere-9

Is it possible to compress static files in IBM WAS 9 without using IBM HTTP Server. If possible please guide me.

I found a way to do it in IHS, in this format.

# Other configuration directives for the virtual host
  
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/javascript text/html image/png image/jpeg

## More configuration directives for the virtual host

Is this correct?